# Restricting claims in Azure App Registration?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Within Azure Active Directory, I have created an App Registration.

For most users, this works great.  They can login to my application via federating in from Azure AD, and their claims are coming through.

For some users, however, they have over 150 group memberships in Azure AD. For them, they receive an HTTP 400 bad request.  I've increased the maxRequestBytes and maxFieldLength of my server according to this post: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/820129/http-sys-registry-settings-for-windows, but it didn't solve the issue for all users. Some received access after this, but there's a handful that still cannot login.

My application only has ~10 groups in Azure AD that it cares about.  I customized my App Registration's manifest to have `"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"`.

Is there a way I can restrict the claims coming out of Azure AD to only the 10 groups that I care about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, this issue is due to too many groups claim in some your Azure AD user access token and you want to limit the group claims.

As far as I know, there is no way to do that. But there will be two workarounds here :

**1.** [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#claims-in-access-tokens) which indicated claims about `groups` and `hasgroups`,  maybe provides some tips to handle your scenario. As the doc indicated, it suggested you to call an API to fetch all user groups if a user has too many group claims.

In your scenario, you will need to check about 10 groups membership with a user. To avoid the issue that too many group claims in your user's token, you can just remove group claims in token and check groups membership with a user with [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#checkmembergroups-check-for-membership-in-a-list-of-groups--).

**2.** Using Azure AD app roles claim instead of groups claim. In Azure AD application, we can create [Add app roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) and assign the role to users or groups. Once be assigned the role , `role` claim will be added in users' token.
As you only care about 10 groups, you can create corresponding app roles and assign the roles to your groups that you cared about(i,e role1 assign to group1).With this,users in groups will have corresponding role claim(i,e , users in group1 will have a role claim:role1) so that we can use this claim to replace `groups` claim .

**What's more**

except for increasing `maxRequestBytes` and `maxFieldLength` of your server, you can try to modify `maxAllowedContentLength` , details see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded) .

Comment: Hi @Dylan McCurry, how is going ? Is your issue solved ?